# Insert a character in the first occuence of a space in a nchar field

Tags: string, sql-server-2008

I have an nchar string field that looks like this:

736TC I-3 Sealed System

I need to insert a '/' in the first blank space, leaving the other blanks alone. How can I do this. Looks like it should be easy, but I'm fairly new at SQL. There are also 297 records that need to be changed.

Comment: Why is this NCHAR and not NVARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF` to inject a `/` at the first instance of a space, which you can find using `CHARINDEX`.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(n NCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES(N'736TC I-3 Sealed System'),(N'34T I-4 Non-Sealed Whatever');

UPDATE @x SET n = STUFF(n, CHARINDEX(N' ',n), 1, N'/');

SELECT n FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
736TC/I-3 Sealed System
34T/I-4 Non-Sealed Whatever
```

This will add the `/` at the end of the string if no space is found, so you may want to limit the `UPDATE` using a `WHERE` clause:

```
  WHERE RTRIM(n) LIKE N'% %';
```

(Or, stop using `NCHAR` for strings that clearly must fluctuate in length.)

Comment: Worked awesome, thanks. And I will take your advice, though in this particular case, it doesn't apply. This is an import table that will populate the active tables. Thanks.